# LINQ GroupBy throwing errors

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda, linq-to-entities

```
 var devSum = repository.Devices
                    .Where(dev => dev.Id == deviceId)
                    .Join(repository.ManagementGroups, device => device.ManagementGroupId, mGroup => mGroup.Id, (device, mGroup) => new { device, mGroup.Name })
                    .Join(repository.DataGroups, device_mGroup => device_mGroup.device.DataGroupId, dGroup => dGroup.Id, (device_mGroup, dGroup) => new { device_mGroup.device, managerName = device_mGroup.Name, dataName = dGroup.Name })
                    .Join(repository.DeviceTypes, d => d.device.TypeId, t => t.Id, (d, t) => new { d.device, d.dataName, d.managerName, TypeName = t.Name })
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Hi, I have the above query joining several tables and all was working. Then I realised some of the foreign keys may be empty.

I've researched the use of `GroupBy` and `DefaultIfEmpty`, and they sounded promising so I tried changing the first `Join` to `GroupJoin` on but this threw an error:

```
 var devSum = repository.Devices
                    .Where(dev => dev.Id == deviceId)
                    .GroupJoin(repository.ManagementGroups, device => device.ManagementGroupId, mGroup => mGroup.Id, (device, mGroup) => new { device, mGroup.Name })
                    .Join(repository.DataGroups, device_mGroup => device_mGroup.device.DataGroupId, dGroup => dGroup.Id, (device_mGroup, dGroup) => new { device_mGroup.device, managerName = device_mGroup.Name, dataName = dGroup.Name })
                    .Join(repository.DeviceTypes, d => d.device.TypeId, t => t.Id, (d, t) => new { d.device, d.dataName, d.managerName, TypeName = t.Name })
                    .SingleOrDefault();

'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you show code that threw exception?

Comment: And the `GroupJoin` version... where?

Comment: Added my edited code, the error is on the line with .GroupJoin at the end of the line where it tries to get mGroup.Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mGroup` in the line `(device, mGroup) => new { device, mGroup.Name }` actually represents the whole collection. You'd need to do a `Select` on it:

```
(device, mGroup) => new { Device = device, NameGroup = mGroup.Select(m => m.Name) }
```

Check out the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx) page on GroupJoin for more info.

Comment: thankyou IronMan, but that throws the error Error 17 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Looks like the MSDN has that in their example. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks, Thats got rid of the errors on that line at least! Ill keep fiddling to try and correct the rest myself and come back and accept this answer when i do.

Comment: The other errors were just chnagign the names on the second line as they had changed on the first. Thanks for your help pal.

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you on your project.